# Templated Stack gives error: invalid conversion from type int to Student

Tags: c++, templates

I haven't posted often so please excuse any bad practices or if this problem is solved in another post, but I couldn't find anything on it.

My issue is that I have a template Stack class that worked fine when I tested it with ints, but I'm supposed to be able to choose between adding ints and Students to a stack for each. In the main file, I have code to add either a student or an int to their respective stacks, depending on what the user chooses, but the compiler is giving me errors saying that I'm trying to add an int to a Student stack and a Student to an int stack. Please help!

these are the errors I'm getting

```
main.cpp:44:21: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const Students*' [-fpermissive]
                     stack->push(value);
                     ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Stack.h:23:10: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void Stack::push(const DataType*) [with DataType = Students]'
     void push(const DataType*);
---
main.cpp:44:21: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const int*' [-fpermissive]
                     stack->push(value);
                     ^
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Stack.h:23:10: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void Stack::push(const DataType*) [with DataType = int]'
     void push(const DataType*);
```

Here is my code

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Students.h"

using namespace std;
int menu()
{
    int response = 0;

    cout << "Menu:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Push a student to the stack" << endl;
    cout << "2. Delete a student from the stack" << endl;
    cout << "3. Print the top element of the stack" << endl;
    cout << "4. Stack type selection" << endl;
    cout << "Please input the option you would like: ";
    cin >> response;
    cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;
    return response;
}
template <class DataType>
bool validateInput(int response, Stack<DataType>* stack, bool isSStack)
/* returns a bool determining if the program should quit or not, 
 * true if the program should quit
*/
{
    bool quit = false;
    if(response >= 1 && response <= 5)
    {
        switch(response)
        {
            case 1:
            {

                if(isSStack)
                {
                    Students* x = new Students();
                    stack->push(x); //this gives an error
                }
                else
                {
                    int value = 0;
                    cout << "What would you like to add? : ";
                    cin >> value;
                    stack->push(value);//and this gives an error
                }    
                //stack->push(x);
                cout << string(100, '\n');
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                cout << string(100, '\n');
                stack->pop();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                cout << string(100, '\n');
                //cout << "Top element is: " <<  x->topStack() << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                cout << "back";
                quit = true;
                break;
            }

        }//end switch
    }
    else
        cout << string(100, '\n') << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl << endl;
      return quit;          
}
int main()
{
    Stack<int>* iStack = new Stack<int>();
    Stack<Students>* sStack = new Stack<Students>();

    cout << "Choose a stack type" << endl << "0. Student" << endl << "1. Integer";// << end;
    bool isSStack = 0;
    cin >> isSStack;

    cout << string(100, '\n');
    bool quit = false;
    while(!quit)//menu asks for which option, which returns the choice into validateInput, which returns if the program should quit
    {
        if(isSStack)
            quit = validateInput(menu(), sStack, isSStack);
        else
            quit = validateInput(menu(), iStack, isSStack);
        //stack->printStack();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Stack.cpp

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::Stack(int size)
{
    maxSize = size;
}

template <class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::~Stack()
{
    if(top == NULL)
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
    else
    {
        StackNode<DataType>* temp = top;
        StackNode<DataType>* deleter = temp;
        while(temp != NULL)//go until it finds null, we past the last node
        {
            deleter = temp;
            temp = temp->next;//move temp down the stack
            delete deleter;   //delete the node we past
        }

    }
}

template <class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::push(const DataType* d)
{
    if(!isFull())
    {
        StackNode<DataType>* newNode= new StackNode<DataType>();
        newNode->data = d;
        newNode->next = top;
        top = newNode;
        numNodes++;
    }else
        cout << "Stack is full" << endl;
}

template <class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::pop()
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        //cout << "pop" << endl;
        StackNode<DataType>* deleter = top;
        top = top->next;
        delete deleter;
        numNodes--;
    }else
        cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
}
template <class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (numNodes <= 0);
}
template <class DataType>
bool Stack<DataType>::isFull() const
{
    return (numNodes >= maxSize);
}

template <class DataType>
DataType Stack<DataType>::topStack() const
{
    return top->data;
}

template <class DataType>
void Stack<DataType>::printStack()
{
    if(!isEmpty())
        {
        StackNode<DataType>* temp = top;
        //cout << "num " << numNodes << endl;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << ", ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }else
        cout << "Empty stack" << endl;
}
```

edit:

I added two pushNew() functions to handle the creation and pushing to the stack but now I'm getting undefined reference errors in those methods

```
void pushNew(Stack<int>* stack, int* x)
{
    cout << "What would you like to add? : ";
    cin >> *x;
    stack->push(x);
}

void pushNew(Stack<Student>* stack, Student* x)
{
    stack->push(x);
}
```

Comment: You're trying to push an `int` into a `Stack` that only accepts `const Student*`. If you want a `Stack` that can hold multiple types in the same instance, you'll need to use something like `std::variant` or `std::any` (the boost versions would work too).

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: The code in your template needs to be generic. You can do things like `stack->push(DataType());`, but if you try to push an int, the template will have errors in it when you instantiate it with `Students` and the other way around.

Comment: there are two stacks instantiated, one Stack<int> and one Stack<Student>. Depending on the isSStack (is Student Stack?) variable I pass one stack to the validateInput. I had to make two cases for the push() method because if the user wants to add a student, the Student contructor asks for the values, but I needed to get the value for an int if they are using the int Stack

Comment: Think you'd want a couple of overloads of `validateInput()` - one taking `Stack<int>` and one that's more generic.  You can't use a runtime value like the bool to chose between the compile-time types of `Stack<int>` and `Stack<const Student*>` (you'd be looking at something like `if constexpr` then)

Comment: @wreckgar23 I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that. Is there not a way to check what type the stack holds and create the right kind of object to add to it? If I made a wrapper class for int and had its constructor ask for the input could I just use one DataType* x = new DataType(); then stack->push(x)?

Comment: @Jackson just create a `pushNew()` function with overloads for `int` and `Student`, and call it from case `1` of your `validateInput()` function.  You won't need the `isSStack` argument then either

Comment: @wreckgar23 I added what you said and it got rid of the errors I had before but now the compiler gives me error: undefined reference to Stack<int>::Stack(int) although I didn't call the compiler and error:undefined reference to Stack<int>::push(int*)

Comment: @Jackson now that overload exists, you need an _explicit template instatiation_ of it for it to be compilable.  so, probably a line `template class Stack<int>;` in `Stack.cpp` should fix that

Comment: do you really have your template code in the source file rather than the header file ? How can the compiler create the correct template ?